# Import a SCORM course to my LMS software in the Database using java

Tags: java, scorm, scorm2004

I am working for an LMS software, we have videos, courses and more... A task has been assigned to me in which I have to import a SCORM project (as a zip file), read its manifest and store SCOs and assets into our database. I am searching for a way to complete this task but could not find anything over the internet. Also, I have to get SCORM 2014 courses only.

I have to store the course in such a way that I can maintain the SCO sequence and retrieve the course using my LMS software.

Is there any feasible way of doing so? Please provide me a solution if anyone can. Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are several versions of SCORM, three of which have significant adoption in LMSs and courseware: [SCORM Version 1.2](https://adlnet.gov/adl-research/scorm/scorm-1-2/), [SCORM 2004 3rd Edition](https://adlnet.gov/adl-research/scorm/scorm-2004-3rd-edition/) and SCORM 2004 4th Edition.  I assume you are referring to support for [SCORM 2004 4th Edition](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_Doc_Suite.zip) since it is the latest.

In [SCORM 2004 4th Edition](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_Doc_Suite.zip) (and really all versions of SCORM), the "import" process in many ways is implementation-specific.  The implementation details of LMSs vary so the requirements are that the courseware run (at run-time) as expected, and this is what is tested.

That being said, generally there are several things typically done by LMSs during import:

1. Validate the imsmanifest.xml file so you know it is valid xml and also conformant to the version of SCORM you are supporting
2. Ensure that the resources listed in the imsmanifest.xml file are present at the specified location in the zip file.
3. Move the web files (the course resources) under the web root so that it can be later launched by the LMS
4. Create a representation of the structure of the course as well as the sequencing information (taken from the imsmanifest.xml file) in the LMSs internal data structure (this is implementation-specific but can be tested during run-time)

In addition, there are other requirements like initializing data model elements during run-time based on values in the manifest.

You can find all of the information about how a course is structured and how course sequencing is defined in the SCORM Content Aggregation Model (CAM) book.  This is available in the SCORM links above (as well as the other mentions below).

You can find all of the information on how an LMS must sequence a course including pseudocode for this process in the SCORM Sequencing and Navigation (S&N) book.

Finally, you can find information about the run-time API and data model in the SCORM Run-Time Environment (RTE) book.

You may find these resources helpful too:

- [SCORM 2004 4th Edition Testing Requirements](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_TR_20090814.pdf) - Describes what requirements are tested by the test suites.  This is what you need to do to be a conformant LMS (or content)
- [SCORM 2004 4th Edition Test Suite Version 1.1.1](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM.2004.4ED.TS_.v1.1.1.zip) and [LMS Test Packages](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM.2004.4ED.TS_.v1.1.1.LMS_.Packages1.zip) - Used to test LMSs and content for SCORM conformance
- [SCORM 2004 4th Edition Sample RTE Version 1.1.1](https://adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM.2004.4ED.SRTE_.v1.1.1.zip) - Example implementation of a SCORM LMS.  This is very lightweight and meant as an example only, but it is conformant to SCORM.  You can look at the import process in this code to see how it is handled by this prototype system.

I hope this helps.  Good luck.